# how to install curl 13.04 with depency error

Tags: apt, software-installation, curl

how to install curl in ubuntu 13.04?
it always throw this error :

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.29.0-1ubuntu3) but 7.29.0-1ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

when using `sudo apt-get update`, it shows:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

here are the steps i had done :

1. using `sudo apt-get install curl`
2. removing google-chrome-stable and chromium browser then `sudo apt-get install curl`
3. use `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean` then run the 1st step again.

also i have tried :
[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

and still throw the same error. at this point i dont know what i did wrong, is curl impossible to install in ubuntu ?

Comment: Just for the sake of it... have you tried `apt-get update`, and not `apt-get upgrade`, before trying to `apt-get install`? You may also try `dpkg --configure -a` and `apt-get -f install` just to make sure you don't have any previous incomplete package installation hanging.

Comment: yup done that and still has the same error

Comment: Which mirror for apt are you using?  Any additional source added?  The error is complaining about a version superior from the one needed by the package, so it's worth checking.

Comment: mirror that i was using : ubuntu.pesat.net.id, i did a third party source for update google-chrome and additional third party software(like faenza for example). is there anyway to solve this? i get this error when i want to install apt-file, that need curl, then i tried apt-get install curl , which give this error

Comment: Well, first try changing your mirror to `us.archive.ubuntu.com` and, then if still not working, disabling the mirrors you added manually.  Doing `apt-get update && apt-get install curl`

Comment: thank you it's working now, changing the mirror solve it (using us.archive.ubuntu). again, thank you very much. is there a way to mark it solved, or do i need to answer my i own question (or you answer it then i mark it as acceptable answer :D ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as discussed from comment up above (with @fboaventura), it turns out that the ubuntu mirror i was using somehow causing the error, change it us.archive.ubuntu.com solve it.
so overall :

1. change the mirror back to `us.archive.ubuntu.com` or ubuntu main server using `update manager>settings`
2. run command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get -f install`
3. run command `sudo apt-get install curl`

that's all hopefully this answer helpful to someone.

Answer (score 7):

Just ran into this problem and since it had a different issue and solution I'm going to post it here.

In my case, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and the error was:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.35.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

In my case, the problem was that I've unchecked, by mistake, `trusty-security` and `trusty-updates` repositories in the `Software & Updates` utility, and perhaps the dependency was going to be installed from one of that repositories:

[image: Software & Updates]

The bottom line is: make sure you have all the needed repositories enabled.

Comment: Wow, worked like a charm.

Comment: Thx...I spent hours of my day chasing down other things, removing PPAs, etc., and all I had to do was check two checkboxes (and download 438 updates).  I've never seen those checkboxes before, so I know I've never unchecked them, but they were unchecked nonetheless.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! The first thing to check when there are no held packages.